# FileVault and other user accounts; repair

Tags: macos, filevault

Suppose I have some moderately sensitive stuff in my user account on a broken Mac. Now bringing it to Apple for repair. (macOS 10.12.4 if that matters)

Apple's advice is:
[image]

OK, but is that enough?

Specifically, I know that an administrator can access another user's files and Apple needs an Administrator's access to my computer. FileVault encrypts the entire disk. If the admin account that Apple has unlocks the DISK does that unlock the files in my account?

Deleting all my files is doable (I have a full back-up) but what a hassle.

Comment: Why do you believe Apple needs administrative access?

Comment: The nature of the errors will need access to the system logs to analyze. System logs require admin account

Comment: what problems are you having?

Comment: Brand new MacBook Pro 15". Constant crashes during sleep (like every night) May be associated with having 2 5k monitors attached. Apple has asked to see the computer.

Comment: This has possibly been answered already: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/93025